# Pass by Reference for a pay calculation program

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I am tasked with writing functions and using pass by reference to send the data to the next functions to calculate data. The assignment was to take an employee number, pay code, and hours worked to determine total pay, and also determine if the given pay code was valid or not.

I'm having trouble with passing variable data from `main()` to the function `code_not_valid()`, and then `code_not_valid()` to `get_pay()`. Here is my source code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

const double MIN_WAGE = 9.87;
using namespace std;

void display(void);
bool code_not_valid(char&);
double get_pay(double, double&, double&);

int main()
{
    display();
    char paycode,yesno;
    int numberemp;
    double employeenumber = 0, hourly_pay = 0, hours, computed_pay = 0,sum;
    do {
        cout << "Enter your Employee number, paycode and hours worked";
        cin >> employeenumber, paycode, hours;
        code_not_valid(paycode);
        get_pay(employeenumber, hourly_pay, hours);
        cout << "Would you like to calculate the pay of another employee (Y/N) ";
        cin >> yesno;
        sum += computed_pay;
        numberemp++;
    } while ((yesno == 'Y') || (yesno == 'y'));
    cout << "\n The payroll for " << numberemp << " employees is $" << sum << endl;
}

void display(void)
{
    cout << "Lab 4b\n";
    cout << "Written by Drew Reif\n\n";
}

bool code_not_valid(char& paycode)
{
    bool done = false;
    while (!done) {

        double hourly_pay;
        if (paycode == 'M' || paycode == 'm') {
            hourly_pay = MIN_WAGE;
            done = true;
        }
        else if ((paycode == 'T') || (paycode == 't')) {
            hourly_pay = MIN_WAGE + 1;
            done = true;
        }
        else if (paycode == 'O' || paycode == 'o') {
            hourly_pay = MIN_WAGE + 2;
            done = true;
        }
        else {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
            cout << "That is not a given pay code \n";
            cout << "Please try again.\n";
            done = false;
        }
    }
}

double get_pay(double employeenumber, double& hourly_pay, double& hours)
{
    double computed_pay;

    if (hours > 40) {
        computed_pay = ((hours - 40) * 1.5 * hourly_pay) + (40 * hourly_pay);
        std::cout << std::fixed;
        std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
        std::cout << "The computed pay is: $" << computed_pay;
        cout << "\n";
    }
    else if (hours <= 40) {
        computed_pay = hourly_pay * hours;
        std::cout << std::fixed;
        std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
        std::cout << "The computed pay is: $" << computed_pay;
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `get_pay` doesn't return anything. You should modify it to

```
double get_pay(double employeenumber, double& hourly_pay, double& hours)
{
    double computed_pay = 0.0;

    // ... computations

    return computed_pay;
}
```

then in `main` you can call that function and assign the returned value

```
double computed_pay = get_pay(employeenumber, hourly_pay, hours);
```

Miscellaneous other comments:

- employeenumber should be `int` instead of `double` (or some other integral type) if it is supposed to be an ID, it wouldn't make sense for an employee ID to be 4.127 for example
- none of the arguments of `code_not_valid` nor `get_pay` need to be passed by reference as they are not modified within the function, and  are primitive types so you don't need to avoid copies
- you don't need to specify `void` for an argument accepting no arguments

Comment: That's the problem, the hourly pay is dependent on the pay code from `code_not_ valid,` and  I need to pass `hourly_pay` to `get_pay`

Comment: @DrewReif You said in your question that `code_not_valid()` should call `get_pay()`, but the code you provided is not attempting to do that. That task makes no sense anyway. I don't think you understand the assignment. But, if that task is true, then `code_not_valid()` only takes in 1 parameter but `get_pay()` takes in 3 parameters, so either `main()` would have to pass additional parameters into `code_not_valid()` so it can then pass them into `get_pay()`, or else `code_not_valid()` would have to declare local variables to pass into `get_pay()`.

Comment: @DrewReif Also, there is no point in having `code_not_valid()` take in the `paycode` by reference, since it is not modifying the `paycode`

Comment: `code_not_valid` produces `hourly_pay` I need that to be passed to `get_pay` so the calculation produce the right pay based on hours and par rate

Comment: @DrewReif Then `code_not_valid()` needs to either `return` the desired `hourly_pay` value, or it needs to take in the `hourly_pay` as a reference parameter.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, how would you verify `paycode` is correct then? The assignment is to use 3 functions to carry out the task.

Comment: @DrewReif since `code_not_valid()` is currently declared as returning a `bool`, you can take in the `hourly_pay` as a reference parameter, and then return `true` only if the `paycode` is valid and `hourly_pay` is updated, otherwise return `false`. Then have `main()` call `get_pay()` only when `code_not_valid()` returns `true`. See the answer I just posted for you.

Answer (score 0):

`code_not_valid()` is declared as returning a `bool`, but is not actually `return`'ing anything (same error with `get_pay()`, too).

For what you are attempting to do, `code_not_valid()` should take in the `hourly_pay` as a reference parameter, and then return `true` only if the `paycode` is valid and `hourly_pay` is updated, otherwise return `false`. Then you can have `main()` call `get_pay()` only when `code_not_valid()` returns `true`.

Also, all of your inputs and outputs should be in `main()`, not in your other functions.  And `main()` has several variables that are not being initialized before they are used.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

const double MIN_WAGE = 9.87;

void display();
bool is_code_valid(char, double&);
double get_pay(double, double);

int main()
{
    char paycode, yesno;
    int numberemp = 0;
    double employeenumber, hourly_pay, hours, computed_pay, sum = 0;

    display();

    do {
        do {
            cout << "Enter the Employee number, paycode, and hours worked: ";

            if (cin >> employeenumber >> paycode >> hours)
                break;

            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "That is not valid input. Please try again.\n";
        }
        while (true);

        while (!is_code_valid(paycode, hourly_pay)) {
            cout << "That is not a valid pay code. Please try again.\n";

            do {
                cout << "Enter the paycode for Employee " << employeenumber << ": ";

                if (cin >> paycode)
                    break;

                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                cout << "That is not valid input. Please try again.\n";
            }
            while (true);
        }

        computed_pay = get_pay(hourly_pay, hours);
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2)
             << "The computed pay is: $" << computed_pay << "\n";

        sum += computed_pay;
        ++numberemp;

        cout << "Would you like to calculate the pay of another employee (Y/N) ";
        cin >> yesno;
    }
    while ((yesno == 'Y') || (yesno == 'y'));

    cout << "\n The payroll for " << numberemp << " employees is $" << sum << endl;
}

void display()
{
    cout << "Lab 4b\n";
    cout << "Written by Drew Reif\n\n";
}

bool is_code_valid(char paycode, double& hourly_pay)
{
    if (paycode == 'M' || paycode == 'm') {
        hourly_pay = MIN_WAGE;
        return true;
    }
    if ((paycode == 'T') || (paycode == 't')) {
        hourly_pay = MIN_WAGE + 1;
        return true;
    }
    if (paycode == 'O' || paycode == 'o') {
        hourly_pay = MIN_WAGE + 2;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

double get_pay(double hourly_pay, double hours)
{
    double computed_pay;

    if (hours > 40) {
        computed_pay = ((hours - 40) * 1.5 * hourly_pay) + (40 * hourly_pay);
    }
    else {
        computed_pay = hourly_pay * hours;
    }

    return computed_pay;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been working on this forever, and you have helped me a ton.